# Can Lucene store more than 100Gb original's documents in index?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I'm writing application what will be manipulate with more than **100Gb** text documents. The size of each document is 2Kb-100Kb.

At first I supposed to **use DBMS** such as MySQL or Firebird to store raw documents with storing index in lucene's index. This approach have some disadvantages. For example, database transactions know nothing about lucene index and vice versa. So I need to synchronize them.

Then I supposed what Lucene can **store entire documents in index**. So I need regulary create index's backups. But it so easy: I can copy entire catalog with index. I use some kind of No SQL storage (i.e. Lucene). And I may don't use DBMS.

What is the best practice: to store original documents in index or not? I'm really don't want use DBMS to such purpose. Is it possible?

Comment: Look at solr and elastic search also they are designed for larger stores and maybe easier to manage and scale easier.  What Bart mentions is valid though don't store the document in the index only the searchable data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not want to store the raw document in a Lucene index, especially the size that you are talking about.  I have done this a couple ways, but both ONLY store the indexed fields in the Lucene index and you have an ID/pointer to the raw document.  I have dealt with indexes well over 100 million records and they work fine on a single server.

The reason this is important is that the build time of the index and manageability of the index dramatically drops if you don't need to store an additional 100 gig of data.

Basically, you need to index all the fields you need for searching/satisfying search queries.  If a user clicks on the item in a grid, I assume you want to show the raw text (the UI pattern is that most of the time you will access a lot of the Lucene fields, but RARELY need to pull down the full binary text file).

The raw access I have used in conjunction with Lucene is:

- SQL Server FILESTREAM, which is optimized for large binary file storage.  It is really fast too.  Not sure if MySQL has this (never worked with it)
- Azure Table Storage, which is a key-value NoSQL cloud database.  That was used to store the binary blobs.

It really doesn't matter what the persisted storage is, as long as it is optimized for larger binary files that can be accessed/streamed fast based off of a key.  You could use an in-memory cache like Redis too as long as Lucene has the ID pointer to access the binary text file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Above you mention Redis as fast solution to store and retrieve entire documents. As I mentioned I have more than 100Gb raw documents and only 12Gb RAM, therefore only small part database can be loaded in RAM. Will this approach work? All what I need: save document and retrieve it by key. And of cause delete it by key.

Сan I use Redis as a fast, simple and reliable (i.e. durability) approach for storing documents? I would prefer use some kind NoSQL without classic DBMS.

Comment: Lucene can work with limited RAM, I have multiple indexes with 100s of millions of records on a server with 14 gRAM.  The queries can be a bit slower, but not by much.  Redis will not work completely for your solution since you only have 12 gig of RAM.  However, the reason I mentioned Redis is that it has a nice feature  of only storing the keys in RAM for fast look up.  Redis can also scale up by adding multiple servers and sharding them potentially giving you 100+ gig of RAM and storing all of the documents in memory if necessary.  You should also test a simple approach of just using a HD...

Comment: and naming your files as the keys or unique key combo.  For example, Lucene retrieves a query of 10 matches.  User clicks on ID = 100.  In your Java/C# etc. code you find the ID that was clicked in Lucene and simply go your documents directory and retrieve file 100.txt.  I assume that you will have this documents directory somewhere since you do need index these files as well. If you can make your text names unique, that could work as well (without the complexity/overhead of a NoSQL database).